# JS : How to use return type of callback function for returning the main callee function

Tags: javascript, callback

I found few good links ([How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function) and [Returning a value from callback function in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js) etc) of SO but they are not not able to provide solution to my problem.

**My Problem**: able to get result of asynchronous call, but how I can use this result for returning of my function?

```
onsubmit = "return checkForm(function(callBackResponse) { alert(callBackResponse) });"
```

Here getting value of callBackResponse either as true or false, and want to use this value as :

```
onsubmit = "return responseFromCallBack;"
```

**EDITED : Here is my async stuff**

```
function checkForm(callback) {return firstCallBack(function secondCallBack(response) {
            if (some conditions) {
                response = false;
                callback(response);
            }
            else {
                response = true;
                callback(response);
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i get ur issue correctly:
you want to "validate" (checkForm()) before submitting?!
in this case set an event listener to the form submit-event...
prevent (`event.preventDefault()`) the default behavior (submit) call your function (checkForm()) if everything is fine, trigger the submit manually ;)
e.g. `document.getElementById('myFormId').submit()`

Cheerio :)

Comment: But here checkForm() is a synchronous function which is getting value from asynchronous callbacks.

Comment: thats why you prevent the form submit do your async stuff and use the successHandler of your async to trigger the formSubmit manually ;)  anyway a bit more code - especially the async stuff would help a lot :)

Comment: well that looks super weird tbh. there is a nice concept called [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) may try something like this: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/faramuqeko/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use nested function call approach and want to check function result than you should use of function and form submit event as follow.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#FormId").submit(function(){
        alert(checkForm());
        return checkForm();
    });
});

function checkForm()
{
    //another core logic
    return anotherfunction();
}

function anotherfunction()
{
    //another core logic than return as per condition true or false.
    return false;
}
```

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/5099/)

Comment: But here checkForm() is a synchronous function which is getting value from asynchronous callbacks.