# Returning undefined value - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the below function which correctly takes from the response the prefix and the suffix of the image and makes a variable result,which holds the url of the venue image. However when i return the result, i keep having undefined.What is going wrong here?

```js
function getPhotoUrl(venue_id,venue_location,venue_query){
  request({
      url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+venue_id+'/photos',
      json:true,
      method: 'GET',
      qs: {
        client_id: 'my_id',
        client_secret: 'my_secret',
        near:venue_location,
        query: venue_query,
        v: '20171114',
        limit: 1
      }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        var result="";
        if (err) {
          console.error(err);
        } else {
          console.log(body.response.photos.items[0].prefix+"300x500"+body.response.photos.items[0].suffix);      
      }
      result=body.response.photos.items[0].prefix+"300x500"+body.response.photos.items[0].suffix;
      return result; 
    }
  );
}
```

```html
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Comment: The A in Ajax is meaningful, search SO for how to deal with the results of an async call.

Comment: You cannot [return from a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `async / await`. Wrap your execution in a Promise to `resolve` the return value and `reject` the error value. This way you can just await on the function and get the return value. Keep in mind `await` stops the execution until the returned promise is fulfilled.

```
function getPhotoUrl(venue_id,venue_location,venue_query){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    request({
      url: 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/'+venue_id+'/photos',
      json:true,
      method: 'GET',
      qs: {
        client_id: 'my_id',
        client_secret: 'my_secret',
        near:venue_location,
        query: venue_query,
        v: '20171114',
        limit: 1
      }
    }, function(err, res, body) {
        var result="";
        if (err)
          reject(err);     
      }
      result=body.response.photos.items[0].prefix+"300x500"+body.response.photos.items[0].suffix;
      resolve(result);
    });
  })
}

await getPhotoUrl('', '', '')
```

Comment: Dear Sir where does the await happen?

Comment: `await getPhotoUrl('', '', '')` last line in my snippet. When you call the method.

Comment: When i call await function, i get await is not defined. I also tried with a promise.then(), i log the data correctly but still i cannot use it and set it to a variable.

Comment: Check out the browser compatibility for `async/await` here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function