# Inside async function, returning value from a callback function returns Promise(undefined)

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, promise, async-await

I'm new to asynchronous programming, 
I'm facing issue similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js), in this question suggested approach uses callbacks but I'm trying to do it using Promises and async-await functions. I get undefined in the console. Here's my example. what am I missing?

```
 //Defining the function
 async query( sql, args ) {
    const rows = this.connection.query( sql, args, async( err, rows ) => 
     { 
        if ( err )
           throw new Error(err); 
        return rows; 
      } );
}

//calling the function here 
 db.query("select 1")
 .then((row) => console.log("Rows",row)) // Rows undefined
 .catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: What you're missing is `await`.

Comment: You don't put `async` on a callback function. You use the Promise constructor, and then you use `await` instead of `then` when you're calling the function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

make your `query` function return a `Promise`

```
function query(sql, args) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve , reject) {
        this.connection.query(sql, args, (err, rows) => {
            if (err)
                reject(err);
            else
                resolve(rows)
        });
    });
}


//calling the function here 
query("select 1")
.then((row) => console.log("Rows",row)) // Rows undefined
.catch((e) => console.log(e));
```

Comment: This works, but can't we do it using async and await in query function?

Comment: If you really wanted to use async/await inside the outside query function, you could "await new Promise(...)". Regardless, you still need a Promise to convert the callback whether you use async/await or just plain Promises.