# How do I return the var in this function from request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-request

Is it possible for me to get the data from `body.message` to use outside that function?

I've tried this so far.

```js
    var codetocheck;
    request({
        url: link,
        json: true
    },function (err, resp, body){
        codetocheck = body.message;//var I want to use outside this function
    })
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

The following solutions can help you to return the data after making an asynchronous call.

Solution 1: You can make use of promises, for any reference, please check the link [promises](https://medium.com/dev-bits/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-32ed3a4fd098)

Solution 2: Please check in here for how to return the data using  callback after making an asynchronous call, [Using callbacks for returning data](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js)