# Return undefined when calling Postgres with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I am following this [guide](https://blog.logrocket.com/setting-up-a-restful-api-with-node-js-and-postgresql-d96d6fc892d8/) to query Node.js to Postgres

My code:

NodeJS:

```
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
    c = db.getUsers(); 
    console.log(c);
  });

const getUsers = (request, response) => {
  pool.query('SELECT * FROM users', (error, results) => {
    if (error) {
      throw error
    }
     //console.log(results) do return data
     return results.rows[0].name //results not working either
  })
}
```

console.log(results) return

```
Result {
  command: 'SELECT',
  rowCount: 2,
  rows:
   [ { id: 1, name: 'Jerry', email: 'jerry@example.com' },
     { id: 2, name: 'George', email: 'george@example.com' } ],
```

}

When I `npm run dev` I get

```
> Ready on http://localhost:3000
undefined
```

SO any way so that I can get `results` data?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Or this: [Returning a value from callback function in Nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23339907/996081)

Comment: The first one does not help.

Comment: The 2nd one give me `callback is not defined`

Comment: You also need to modify the way you call `getUsers` and its parameters. I also suggest reading: [What are callbacks?](https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/control-flow/what-are-callbacks/)

Comment: yeah seems like I forget that getUsers also it works. Thanks a lot.