# running a forEach on an array passed to ejs template

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have an array of objects being pulled from Mongo, which looks like this:

```js
[
  {
    _id: 5f2038de019c99595df20977,
    fromDoctor: 'Dummyname1',
    Message: 'dummymessage1'
  },
  {
    _id: 5f2038e5019c99595df20978,
    fromDoctor: 'Dummyname2',
    Message: 'dummymessage2'
  }
]
```

I'd like to insert this array, which i call allMessages, into an EJS file, displaying them all, something like this:

```js
    <div class="NoticeMessage">
        <p>Posted by ${notice.fromDoctor}</p>
        </br>
        <p>Message</p>
        </br>
        <p>${notice.Message}</p>
    </div>
        ;
```

I'm attempting to pass the array to ejs when /board (the route) is called, like this:

```js
res.render('Board', {Messages : allMessages});
```

(I have confirmed that the array is defining properly, allMessages is equal to above array)

I'd like to insert the array and run .forEach with above template code on it, creating a new NoticeMessage for each object in the array, and inserting them into this:

```js
<div class="row mt-5">
    <div class="card card-body">
        <h2>Message board</h2>
        </br>
        </br>
        <!--INSERT HERE-->
    </div>
</div>
```

But i really don't know how to go about it. Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `for .. of`-loop to render the contents of each message:

```
<% for(const notice of Messages) {%>
    <div class="NoticeMessage">
        <p>Posted by <%= notice.fromDoctor %></p>
        <p>Message</p>
        <p><%= notice.Message %></p>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

EDIT:

To handle the asynchronicity just return the promise from the [`toArray()`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/AggregationCursor.html#toArray) function, and await this in your controller. After that, do the rendering:

```
// in your model get rid of the callback and just return the promise
async function loadMessages() {
 return mongoose.connection.db.collection("BulletBoardDB").find().toArray();
}

// in your controller await the promise and do the rendering
renderBoard = async(req, res) => {
    let allMessages  = await this.boardModel.loadMessages();
    console.log(allMessages);
    res.render('Board', {
        Messages: allMessages
    });
};
```

Comment: Seems like this would be the solution, but whenever I run this, It's not loading anything in at all, just seems like there isn't any code. It's not returning any errors either, what could be going wrong?

Comment: Are you using `mongoose` to fetch the data from mongo?

Comment: Well, in a way - I'm fetching it using native mongoDB inside a mongoose connection, like this:

```js
async loadMessages() {
        let allMessages = "";
        mongoose.connection.db.collection("BulletBoardDB").find()
            .toArray((error, result) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log(result);
            allMessages = result;
        });
    }
```

which is returning the array i posted in the original question

Comment: You need to make sure to the rendering inside the callback - updated the answer. The reason for this has been explained countless times on SO :) Check this for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js

Comment: Ah, I see - Theres only one issue with that, which is that i'm being force to follow strict MVC by tutors for my exam project, so the loadMessages() function is defined as a method of the boardModel, which is being called together with the res.render inside the boardController, as follows:
```js
renderBoard = async (req, res) => {
        let allMessages = "";
        this.boardModel.loadMessages();
        console.log(allMessages);
        res.render('Board', {Messages : JSON.parse(allMessages)});
    };
```

Sorry i left this out originally, should've been more specific

Comment: `toArray` already returns a promise - so you can just await this in your controller. I've updated the answer once more.

Comment: There's no way to pass the array from my model.js to the controller.js and run it from there? the issue is definitely that allMessages is undefined, as it's not being passed there :/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing. It is an async operation though - you need to await it. Once it's finished the returned promise will resolve to the array of data!

Comment: Its returning now, the console is logging succesfully! I'm being returned an error in the browser now that "Messages is not iterable", what could be causing this?

Comment: Have you tried not using `JSON.parse(allMessages)`? Try it like I did in my answer.

Comment: ```js  renderBoard = async (req, res) => {
        let allMessages = await this.boardModel.loadMessages();
        console.log(allMessages);
        res.render('Board', {Messages: allMessages});
    };```
Yea, still just returning that it isn't iterable :/

Answer (score 0):

Does the following help you?
The render function:

```
res.render('Board', {Messages : JSON.parse(allMessages)});
```

For your ejs file:

```
<div class="row mt-5">
<div class="card card-body">
    <h2>Message board</h2>
    </br>
    </br>
    <% Messages.forEach(function(message){ %>
    <div class="NoticeMessage">
      <p>Posted by <%= message.fromDoctor %></p>
    </br>
    <p>Message</p>
    </br>
    <p><%= message.Message %></p>
</div>
 <% }) %>
</div>
```

Comment: This results in the page just loading indefinitely, no clue what kind of error is happening as nothing is logging, and it's not returning anything in the browser :/