# How to pass data from javascript to node and response back with other data?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ajax, callback

[POSSIBLY A DUPLICATE]

I have been working on a simple form that will accept the following input element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input01" name="job_title" placeholder="Enter a job title (e.g. Engineering)"> 
<button class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" id="form_submit_button">Search</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="parser.js"></script>
```

What I want to do is to:

1. Pass the input from browser to client-side JavaScript.
2. Make an AJAX request `success` to the server-side NODE.
3. NODE will receive data (user input) and perform some tasks
4. NODE will respond back to client-side JavaScript.
5. AJAX will receive the respond `complete` and modify some HTML.

JS CODE:

```
(function($){
    "use strict";
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        var $this = $(window);

        $("#form_submit_button").on("click", function () {

            //GET VALUES FROM USER INPUT AND STORE IN VARIABLES
            var job_title = $("#input01").val();
            var job_country = $("#input02").val();
            var job_contract = $("#input03").val();
            var job_education = $("#input04").val();
            
            var userInput = JSON.stringify({
                job_title, 
                job_country,
                job_contract,
                job_education
            });
            
            //PASS DATA INTO NODE VIA HTTP POST REQUEST
            myAjaxCall("POST", "http://localhost:80/test01", userInput, function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        });

    });
})();

function myAjaxCall(method, url, userInput, callback) {

    $.ajax({
        datatype: "jsonp",
        contentType: "applicatin/json",
        type: method,
        url: url,
        data: userInput,
        success: function (userInput) {
            console.log("success");
            console.log(userInput);
        },
        complete: function(responseData) {
            console.log("complete");
            return callback(responseData);
        }
    })
}
```

NODE:

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
app.use(cors({
    origin: '*',
    optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
}));
app.post("/test01", (req, res) => {

    //get data 
    //do some stuff

    //data to be returned back to client
    var object = {
        message: "hello world"
    }

    res.status(200).send(object).end(); //THIS DOESN'T RELOAD PAGE BTW!!!
});
app.listen(80, ()=> {
    console.log("\n    > Server listening on port: 80");
});
```

The NODE works okay when accessing `http://localhost` from the local machine, but when I try the requests on my website (hosted on `noip.com`), that is where it gets tricky. Basically, when I run the above code on my local machine through the public URL that uses my public IP address, it will work fine and return the results I want. I assume this is because the NODE environment is set on my computer locally.

CONSOLE LOG ON LOCAL COMPUTER:

```
success
parser.js:42 {message: "hello world"}
parser.js:45 complete
parser.js:24 {readyState: 4, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, responseJSON: {message: "hello world"}, responseText: "{"message":"hello world"}", ...}
```

However, when I do this request from another computer also by using the public URL, it will give me an error JSON object back, without the information I want (responseJSON or responseText). I can't figure out why this is happening.

CONSOLE LOG FROM ANOTHER MACHINE:

```
jquery.min.js:2 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost/test01' from origin 'http://192.168.178.50' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost/test01 net::ERR_FAILED
parser.js:45 complete
parser.js:24 
{readyState: 0, getResponseHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, setRequestHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}
abort: ƒ (e)
always: ƒ ()
catch: ƒ (e)
done: ƒ ()
fail: ƒ ()
getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ ()
getResponseHeader: ƒ (e)
overrideMimeType: ƒ (e)
pipe: ƒ ()
progress: ƒ ()
promise: ƒ (e)
readyState: 0
setRequestHeader: ƒ (e,t)
state: ƒ ()
status: 0
statusCode: ƒ (e)
statusText: "NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Failed to load 'http://localhost/test01'."
then: ƒ (t,n,r)
_proto_: Object
```

I have read the following SO posts but couldn't figure out what I did wrong:

- [Returning a value from callback function in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23339907/returning-a-value-from-callback-function-in-node-js)
- [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

---

UPDATE:

Based on Quentin comment and this [link](https://enable-cors.org/server_expressjs.html) i have modified the code. This will work okay on local computer but not on another computer:

```
app.use(
    cors({
        origin: 'http://192.168.178.50',
        methods: "GET, POST",
        optionsSuccessStatus: 200, // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
        preflightContinue: false,
    }),
    function(req, res, next) {
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.178.50"); // update to match the domain you will make the request from
        res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
        next();
    }
);
```

Comment: You seem to be mistaken on one thing, node is javascript, what you probably meant was `frontend to backend/server` not `javascript to node`

Comment: Thanks for the note, question has been updated

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors#enabling-cors-pre-flight

Comment: Question have been updated